# Change select option value on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-select

I've got a dropdown with a list of regions, I'd like the drop down to auto select an item based on the variable value I assign.

Here's the code.

```
<select name="_sft_location[]" class="sf-input-select" title="">
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0" data-sf-count="0" data-sf-depth="0" value="">All Locations</option>
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-177" data-sf-count="2" data-sf-depth="0" value="all">Location A</option>
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-139" data-sf-count="24" data-sf-depth="0" value="vic">Location B</option>
</select>
```

So for instance, if I have a PHP variable `$defaultLocation = "Location B"`, the dropdown should autoselect "Location B" from the list on page load.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `selected` attribute of `<option>`

So, if Location A and Location B needs to be selected, your code would be:

If your options are getting generated run time from PHP, you need to add `if` condition there.

```
<select name="_sft_location[]" class="sf-input-select" title="">
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0" data-sf-count="0" data-sf-depth="0" value="">All Locations</option>
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-177" data-sf-count="2" data-sf-depth="0" value="all" selected="selected">Location A</option>
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-139" data-sf-count="24" data-sf-depth="0" value="vic" selected="selected">Location B</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary option will work to achieve what you want, If you want to learn deep about select element default attributes here is [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).

```
<select class="sf-input-select" name="_sft_location[]" title="">
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0" data-sf-count="0" data-sf-depth="0" value="">
        All Locations
    </option>
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-177" data-sf-count="2" data-sf-depth="0" value="all">
        Location A
    </option>
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-139" data-sf-count="24" data-sf-depth="0" value="vic"
    <?php (!empty($defaultLocation) && $defaultLocation == 'Location B' ? 'selected':'')
    ?>>
        Location B
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it will help you

```
$(".sf-input-select select").val("Location B");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help. I ended up with this solution

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
     $('select').find('option[value=Location B]').attr('selected','selected');
    });
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

<sup>No need for javascript/jquery to do this while you just want to change the selection without code depending on this change onload</sup>

With a simple php function you can do this .. You can do it inline without need to create a function but I prefer to create a function

```
<?php 
  function defaultLocation($location){
     global $defaultLocation;
     return ($defaultLocation == $location) ? 'selected' : '';
  }
?>

<select name="_sft_location[]" class="sf-input-select" title="">
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0" data-sf-count="0" data-sf-depth="0" value="">All Locations</option>
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-177" data-sf-count="2" data-sf-depth="0" value="all" <?php echo defaultLocation('Location A'); ?>>Location A</option>
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-139" data-sf-count="24" data-sf-depth="0" value="vic" <?php echo defaultLocation('Location B'); ?>>Location B</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally we use drop down values instead of texts, i.e 'all' or 'vic' instead of 'Location A' or 'Location B'. 
Any way for your question, you can also make use of 'if' statement:

```
<select name="_sft_location[]" class="sf-input-select" title="">
<option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0" data-sf-count="0" data-sf-depth="0" value="">All Locations</option>
<option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-177" data-sf-count="2" data-sf-depth="0" value="all"  <?php if($defaultLocation == "Location A") {echo 'selected';} ?> >Location A</option>
<option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-139" data-sf-count="24" data-sf-depth="0" value="vic" <?php if($defaultLocation == "Location B") {echo 'selected';} ?> >Location B</option>
```